# Updating form issues

Tags: html, mysql, codeigniter

I have this form and on the form you can add rows of inputs and each row is saved as a component. I have an edit function that lets you edit the forms existing info so if you added 3 components in the add function, three components would show up in the edit function.

The problem I'm having is these rows can be individually removed on edit and the tables should be updated as well. The table `campaign_components` does because the function deletes at the start of the function and inserts at the end of the function. The table communication does not.

I need to add a delete query into this but every attempt I've made erases more that it should.

**MODEL:**

```
public function editCampaign($campaign_id, $data) {

        $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "campaigns SET campaign_name = '" . $this->db->escape($data['campaign_name']) . "', campaign_giving_goal = '" . (float)$data['campaign_giving_goal']
        . "', code = '" . $this->db->escape($data['code']) . "', campaign_active = '" . $this->db->escape($data['campaign_active']) . "', campaign_giving_count_goal = '" . (float)$data['campaign_giving_count_goal'] . "', campaign_owner = '" . $this->db->escape($data['campaign_owner']). "'
        , date_beginning = '" . $this->db->escape($data['date_beginning']). "', date_ending = '" . $this->db->escape($data['date_ending']). "' WHERE campaign_id = '" . (int)$campaign_id . "'");

        $parent_id = 0;

        $this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "campaign_components WHERE campaign_id = '" . (int)$campaign_id . "'");
        //$this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "communication WHERE campaign_id = '" . (int)$campaign_id . "'");
        foreach($data['component_module'] as $component_data) {

            if ($component_data['component_type'] =='EVENT'){

            if(isset($component_data['component_parent_id'])){
                $parent_id = $component_data['component_parent_id'];

                $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "product SET model = '" . $this->db->escape($component_data['component_type']) . "', date_starting = '" . $this->db->escape($component_data['component_start_date']). "', date_ending = '" . $this->db->escape($data['date_ending']). "', date_added = NOW() WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$parent_id . "'");
                $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description SET name = '" . $this->db->escape($component_data['component_name']) . "', language_id = '1' WHERE product_id ='" . (int)$parent_id . "'");
            }else{

                $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product SET model = '" . $this->db->escape($component_data['component_type']) . "', date_starting = '" . $this->db->escape($data['date_beginning']). "', date_ending = '" . $this->db->escape($data['date_ending']). "', date_added = NOW()");
                $parent_id = $this->db->getLastID();


                $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description SET name = '" . $this->db->escape($component_data['component_name']) . "', language_id = '1', product_id ='" . (int)$parent_id . "'");
                $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category SET category_id = '82', product_id ='" . (int)$parent_id . "' ");

            }

        }else{

            if(isset($component_data['component_parent_id'])){
                $parent_id = $component_data['component_parent_id'];
      //  $this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "communication WHERE communication_id = '" . (int)$parent_id . "'");
                $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "communication SET subject = '" . $this->db->escape($component_data['component_name']) . "', channel = '" . $this->db->escape($component_data['component_type']) . "', status = '" . $this->db->escape($component_data['component_status']) . "'
                , status_date = '" . $this->db->escape($component_data['component_start_date']). "', status = '" . $this->db->escape($component_data['component_status']) . "', created_by = '" . $this->db->escape($component_data['component_owner']) . "', date_added = NOW(), campaign_id = '" . (int)$campaign_id . "' WHERE communication_id = '" . (int)$parent_id . "'");
        }else{
                $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "communication SET subject = '" . $this->db->escape($component_data['component_name']) . "', channel = '" . $this->db->escape($component_data['component_type']) . "', status = '" . $this->db->escape($component_data['component_status']) . "'
                , status_date = '" . $this->db->escape($component_data['component_start_date']). "', created_by = '" . $this->db->escape($component_data['component_owner']) . "', date_added = NOW(), campaign_id = '" . (int)$campaign_id . "'");

                $parent_id = $this->db->getLastID();
            }
        }

        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "campaign_components SET component_type = '" . $this->db->escape($component_data['component_type']) . "', component_status = '" . $this->db->escape($component_data['component_status']) . "'
        , component_owner = '" . $this->db->escape($component_data['component_owner']). "', campaign_id = '" . (int)$campaign_id . "', parent_id = '" . (int)$parent_id . "'");
    }

        $this->cache->delete('parent_id');

        return $campaign_id;
    }
```

CONTROLLER:

```
public function edit() {
        $this->load->language('campaigns/campaign');

        $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));

        $this->load->model('campaigns/campaign');
        if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validateForm()) {
            $campaign_id = $this->request->get['campaign_id'];

            $this->model_campaigns_campaign->editCampaign($campaign_id, $this->request->post);

            $this->session->data['success'] = $this->language->get('text_success');

            $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('campaigns/campaign', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . $url, true));
        }

        $this->getForm();
    }
```

[image]

Comment: can you please added the controller ?

Comment: Can you please be more specific. What does "Deleting more than it should" mean, and what are you expecting it to do?

Comment: The code has been updated to show the controller. What I meant by more than it should is, if I add the delete query code near the delete campaign_components(commented out code) it removes all records that have the same campaign id. It needs the campaign to link the records together between the tables but it needs the communication_id to differentiate the rows(each row in the pic is a record. Ive move the code around(into the else )to no avail